# MySQL How can I convert columns to rows?

Tags: mysql, sql

There is a column representing 24 hours. 
Data comes in every 15 minutes. 
For example, at 10:15, the value is entered in the DateTime column of the 10H column.
But what I want,
I want to display time and value line by line by combining time column and datetime...

- as is for 2020-11-12 at 01:30 
  row: 2020-11-12 00:30 
  column: 1H
- to be for 2020-12-12 at 01:30
  row : 2020-11-12 01:30
  column : value

as is

```
DateTime             0H  1H
2020 11 10 00:00:00  979 958 
2020 11 10 00:15:00  987 954 
2020 11 10 00:30:00  987 958 
2020 11 10 00:45:00  960 956 
2020 11 11 00:00:00    0 0 
2020 11 11 00:15:00    0 0 
2020 11 11 00:30:00    0 0 
2020 11 11 00:45:00    0 0 
2020 11 12 00:00:00  995 995 
2020 11 12 00:15:00  991 993 
2020 11 12 00:30:00 1000 993 
2020 11 12 00:45:00  993 996
```

to be

```
DateTime             Value
2020 11 10 00:00:00    979 
2020 11 10 00:15:00    987 
2020 11 10 00:30:00    987 
2020 11 10 00:45:00    960 

2020 11 10 01:00:00    958 
2020 11 10 01:15:00    954 
2020 11 10 01:30:00    958 
2020 11 10 01:45:00    956 

2020 11 11 00:00:00      0
2020 11 11 00:15:00      0
2020 11 11 00:30:00      0
2020 11 11 00:45:00      0

2020 11 11 01:00:00      0 
2020 11 11 01:15:00      0 
2020 11 11 01:30:00      0 
2020 11 11 01:45:00      0 

2020 11 12 00:00:00    995 
2020 11 12 00:15:00    991 
2020 11 12 00:30:00   1000 
2020 11 12 00:45:00    993 

2020 11 12 01:00:00    995 
2020 11 12 01:15:00    993 
2020 11 12 01:30:00    993 
2020 11 12 01:45:00    996
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want `union all`:

```
select datetime, `0H` as value
from t
union all
select datetime + interval 1 hour, `1H`
from t;
```

You can also do this using `cross join`:

```
select (datetime + interval h hour) as datetime,
       (case when h.h = 0 then `0H` else `1H` end) as value
from t cross join
     (select 0 as h union all select 1 as h) h
```

Comment: @Strawberry: I bet you'll have difficulties to find any kind of SQL question that Gordon Linoff did not answered already....

Comment: @GMB True, but in this instance, it's the same author

Comment: @Strawberry: yes, I got that. The questions are not exactly similar though, and same goes for the answers. I have seen Gordon closing perfectly identical questions as duplicates more than once (and I tend to do the same when I catch such pattern).